# How to convert Elasticsearch Query Builder response into CSV format in Java?

Tags: java, json, csv, elasticsearch

I am trying to Convert my Elasticsearch query response i.e. in Json format into CSV format by using the Json2Flat library but it is not working. Here is the Java code.
The query argument of Query Builder is coming from URL using Java Servlets and Jetty Server.

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(index) 
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("user", query))
.setSize(100)
.execute() 
.actionGet(); 
 System.out.println("searchKeyWord : " + response); 
  String doc=response.toString();
JFlat flatMe = new JFlat(doc);

//directly write the JSON document to CSV
 flatMe.json2Sheet().write2csv("/home/alihas/Desktop/file.json");
//directly write the JSON document to CSV but with delimiter
 flatMe.json2Sheet().write2csv("/home/alihas/Desktop/file1.json",'|');
```

The error that I got is:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
com/google/gson/JsonElement
Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/JsonElement
at Elasticsearch.elasticsearch.searchKeyWord(elasticsearch.java:296)
at Elasticsearch.elasticsearch.mainMe(elasticsearch.java:98)
at Elasticsearch.QuerySelector.doGet(QuerySelector.java:39)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:530)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:227)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:931)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:361)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:867)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:113)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:337)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1005)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:560)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:222)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:417)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:474)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:437)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Exception is suggesting a classpath problem: NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Looks to me like you're not including the gson jar file in your class path.

Comment: if I include gson jar file then it gives me following error:                                                HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    com/jayway/jsonpath/Configuration
Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jayway/jsonpath/Configuration